# Excel - Displaying missing values

Tags: excel, formula

I'm looking for some assistance, I'm trying to work out a way to take data from two values and display what the difference is in another box.

Example

```
     A                          B
1  The cat and dog           |
2  The and dog               |  cat
3  cat and dog               |  the
4  the cat                   |  and dog
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The perfect outcome should be "the cat and dog" if not display what is missing in the field.

Comment: Is it not straight forward? A1 is showing the cat and dog, therefore in B1 nothing is there as it is the perfect statement.

A2 "The and dog" what is missing is "cat" which is displayed in B2 as it is not the correct statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a UDF:

```
Function LeftOver(Str1 As String, Str2 As String) As String
Dim spltstr

For Each spltstr In Split(Str2)
    Str1 = Trim(Replace(Str1, spltstr, "", , , vbTextCompare))
Next spltstr

LeftOver = Replace(Str1, "  ", " ")
End Function
```

Then you would put this in B1:

```
=LeftOver($A$1,A1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA, you could create a custom function that splits the minuend into an array, parses the subtrahend into a dictionary, and loops through the minuend array to remove elements in the subtrahend to return the difference. Hope that was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function WhatsMissing(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    Dim IsInThere As Boolean
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        ary1 = Split(.Trim(LCase(s1)), " ")
        ary2 = Split(.Trim(LCase(s2)), " ")
    End With
    For Each a1 In ary1
        IsInThere = False
        For Each a2 In ary2
            If a2 = a1 Then IsInThere = True
        Next a2
        If Not IsInThere Then WhatsMissing = WhatsMissing & " " & a1
    Next a1
End Function
```

[image]